# Keep asking for number and add and keep a counter and exit if entered letter Q

Tags: java

I dont know why its not working, the goals is have the program loop and keep asking you to enter a number and quit when its you enter Q. Whiles its looping it should add the numbers inputed and keep track the amount of times the number is inputted. When the user enters Q the program should exit and print the average

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);


        double counter = 0;
        double total;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String testString = scn.next();

       while(!testString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
            double number1 = Double.parseDouble(testString);

            total = number1 + testString;
            System.out.print(number1);
            ++counter;
            scn.hasNextDouble();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it would be usefull if you let me know what im doing wrong, and kind of guide me through it. Im still new to programming, sorry.

Comment: i had a while loop but the program kept running and crashing

Comment: Have you considered updating `testString` **in** your *loop*?

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are a few things in your code that are incorrect. Inside of your while loop you use `scn.hasNextDouble` this isn't doing anything to help your code make its way through the while loop. Since you are checking `testString` for your while loop I suggest updating testString like you did in the beginning of the code.

Also the line `total = number1 + testString;` doesn't make any sense and you should check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for more info on primatives.

Im unsure on why you are throwing a FileNotFoundException you are using standard system input(keyboard) and dont need to use that

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need a loop to continuously check the code. Basically, the program reaches the if statement and checks whether it's true for the moment or not. It is not true, as you haven't entered the letter q yet. So, the program just skips over the if statement, and ends itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Elliott Frisch mentioned, you need to update `testString` inside your loop.

The part that repeats itself starts with the `while`'s `{` and ends with the closing `}`.

So you are *not* repeating

```
    String testString = scn.next();
```

Try putting that line *inside* your while loop.

```
   String testString;

   while(!testString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
        testString = scn.next();
        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(testString);

        total = number1 + testString;
        System.out.print(number1);
        ++counter;
    }
```

Now you'll keep grabbing stuff as long as it's not 'q'.

To improve that, it would be better to change your guard on the while loop to:

```
while (!scn.hasNextDouble()) {
    // blah blah
}
```

That way it keeps reading until it finds something that doesn't match `Double`, so any letter will stop it.

Also better would be to use `scn.nextDouble()` instead of `scn.next()`, as that way you can be sure to get `Double`s, and you don't need to check for 'q', and you don't need to parse the `String`.

```
while (scn.hasNextDouble()) {
    Double number = scn.nextDouble();
    total = total + number;
    counter++;
}
```